# WordPress hide dropdown when clicked anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a multiselect dropdown with jQuery. There is a problem. When I click on drop menu it open, but when click outside the box it doesn't hide.

```
<dl class="dropdown" id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none"> 
<dt>
<li> 
    <span class="hida">ژانر فیلم<span>   
        <i style="display: block;position: absolute"></i>
</li>
</dt>
    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
            <li><label><input name="product_cat" value="action" type="checkbox"><span>action</span></label></li>
            <li><label><input name="product_cat" value="animation" type="checkbox"><span>animation</span></label></li>
            <li><label><input name="product_cat" value="history" type="checkbox"><span>history</span></label></li>
            <li><label><input name="product_cat" value="horror" type="checkbox"><span>horror</span></label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

jquery for this is:

```
$(".dropdown dt li").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
} 

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.mutliSelect input[type="select"]').on('click', function() {

    var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="option"]').val(),
        title = $(this).val() + ",";

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
        $('.multiSel').append(html);
        $(".hida").hide();
    } else {
        $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
        var ret = $(".hida");
        $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);
    }

});
```

What in the world should I do to fix my dropdown?

Comment: Where does `dropdownc` come from? You have a class `dropdown` but not with a `c`.

Comment: I edited it ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(".dropdown dt li").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
} 

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.mutliSelect input[type="select"]').on('click', function() {

    var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="option"]').val(),
        title = $(this).val() + ",";

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
        $('.multiSel').append(html);
        $(".hida").hide();
    } else {
        $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
        var ret = $(".hida");
        $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);
    }

});

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
                    {
  var container = $(".hida");

  if (!container.is(e.target) 
      && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
  {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dropdown" id="hiddenDiv"> 
<dt>
<li> 
    <span class="hida">ژانر فیلم<span>   
        <i style="display: block;position: absolute"></i>
</li>
</dt>
    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
            <li><label><input name="product_cat" value="action" type="checkbox"><span>action</span></label></li>
            <li><label><input name="product_cat" value="animation" type="checkbox"><span>animation</span></label></li>
            <li><label><input name="product_cat" value="history" type="checkbox"><span>history</span></label></li>
            <li><label><input name="product_cat" value="horror" type="checkbox"><span>horror</span></label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: It didnt work. I use woocommerce 3.4.2 and wordpress 4.9.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".dropdownc dd ul").hide();
});
```